# Render an array of JSON Objects returned from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I query an API which returns an array of items, with each item having multiple things within (id, date, time, description, etc) [image]

How can I render this information similar to this:

[image]

What I have tried:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className = "OneStock">
        <Container fluid>
            
            {this.props.value.map(item =>(<Row><span>{item.description}</span><Badge>{item.option_symbol}</Badge><span>{item.strike_price}</span></Row>))}
        
        </Container>
    </div>

    )
}
```

This doesn't render anything, but I want to parse & map ALL the info before rendering it. So, each item on a separate row, with the information within item displayed in columns like the image above

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Returning `<Row>` in your map should get you on the right track

Comment: @charlietfl How do I map everything within the item? Not just option_symbol, but ID, Description, etc

Comment: Conceptual example: `map(item =>(<Row><span>{item.time}</span><Badge>{item.option_symbol}</Badge><span>{item.strike}</span></Row>))`

Comment: Excellent! let me try and get back to you @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl Unfortunately didn't work. Should I put this in another function or directly in my render return?

Comment: "didn't work"...what happened? What errors thrown? Whole this.props.value.map needs to be wrapped in `{}` in render() same way you did in question

Comment: @charlietfl updated code in question, it doesn't display anything on the screen

Comment: @charlietfl Nevermind, changing the <span> to <badge> worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: At a minimum, try this (note that I added the `id` property to the Row. Every element returned from a map should have a unique `key`: `map(item =>(<Row key={item.id}><span>{item.time}</span><Badge>{item.option_symbol}</Badge><span>{item.strike}</span></Row>))`